# Option to Search Entire Chatroom History by Stars

Tags: feature-request, chat

This probably isn't a terrifically *useful* feature to request, but I think it would be nice to be able to look at all of the starred messages in a particular chatroom, and sort the results by number of stars.

[Semi-Relevant Discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6396149#6396149)

Comment: I'll build that for you, if you stop abusing chat flags. Deal?

Comment: What is *that* supposed to mean?  Stop getting flagged?  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Both stop getting flagged, and stop flagging senselessly.